# Why does input type checkbox act differently when it's checked?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, styles

My input type = "checkbox" acts differently when it's checked, it only works for one element for the first input type="checkbox", however for other inputs it works incorrectly.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    background-color: #d9a83f;
}
```

```html
<div class="first_body">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox__id" class="checkbox regular_checkbox" value="value" />
    <label for="checkbox__id">Европейская</label>
</div>
<div class="last_body">
    <div class="last_body_child">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox__id" class="checkbox regular_checkbox" value="value" />
        <label for="checkbox__id">Италия</label>
    </div>
    <div class="last_body_child">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox regular_checkbox" />
        <label for="checkbox__id">Франция</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

When you click other, only first element with input type="checkbox" is checked, even though you clicking other inputs. Each separate input should be highlighted separately.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your id for label-for attribute is matching the first checkbox and hence its only checking/unchecking first item. Make sure your ids for checkboxes match the label for attribute. I think this is what you want: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h3mopzos/)

```
<div class="first_body">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox__id" class="checkbox regular_checkbox" value="value" />
<label for="checkbox__id">Европейская</label>
</div>
<div class="last_body">
<div class="last_body_child">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox__id_2" class="checkbox regular_checkbox" value="value" />
    <label for="checkbox__id_2">Италия</label>
</div>
<div class="last_body_child">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox__id_3" class="checkbox regular_checkbox" />
        <label for="checkbox__id_3">Франция</label>
    </div>
</div>
```